# Create a list out of lists of lists of varying dimensions

Tags: python, list

I have multiple lists of lists where the dimensions of each vary, for example

```
list_1 = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6], [7,8,9,10,11,12]]
.
.
.
list_n = [[1,2,3], [4,5]]
```

For each of the lists above, I am looking to make flat lists, such as

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
list_n = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have seen another stackoverflow answer [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) which works for 2D lists, but I may have many more dimensions in my lists.

Is mechanically looping through each list the best way of doing this, with use of isinstance(element, list) to check if lists still exist in the list of lists?

Or is there a elegant solution that would work on lists of any dimension?

Comment: `but I may have many more dimensions in my lists` - Can you show a sample please?

Comment: for example list_2 = [1,[2,3,4,[6,7]], [8,9], [10,[11,12]]]